# Live data loading with JQgrid

Tags: php, jqgrid, live

I have a system that is using the JQgrid  to load large amount of data via XML.
the real performance issue is that every row is been processed on the php for a long time (calculation fetching and all kinds of php goodness ..) so i was wondering if its possible to get each processed row LIVE - meaning that the total amount of grid load is the same but the user experience  is better since he will see the grid slowly fill out..

Is that possible at all ?

Comment: Please add more details with what you want to accomplish, so that more users can provide suitable answers to your question.

Comment: Or optimise your "calculation fetching and all kinds of php goodness..." so that the load time issue you seem to be experiencing is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this by changing your grid loading method.  Rather than use the simple means of fetching the data (by directly accessing it within the grid via the url: 'myXMLData.php' parameter), I would instead manually populate the grid with a call to [`addXmlData`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods).

Basically, the process would be to initialize your grid with empty values, and then to kick off a request to the server to start building your response.  This request would return immediately, passing back a reference to the XML location that will be built-up over time.  Also, this initial request will fork a background task on the server which will actually do the processing and XML construction to a temporary cache location (building it up in that same location that was returned as a reference).  On the browser side, that reference is saved, and periodically polled to check for new XML data (using jQuery Ajax methods).  After getting the response from each of these polls, use the addXmlData() method I linked above to load the jqGrid with the current set of data.  The polling can stop when the response from the server contains all the rows you expect.  You will also want a task on the server that runs periodically to clean up the XML cache.

Comment: Thank you for your response ... - i will check out the addXmlData you suggested..